# Filtering DataFrame on groups with at least one matching criterion

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with a DataFrame having the following structure:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'group' : [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5], 
                   'id' : ['A_410', 'B_171', 'X_218', 'A_685', 'B_305', 'C_407', 'X_202', 'B_989', 'C_616', 'X_267', 'A_112', 'C_358'], 
                   'active' : [-1, -1, 999, -1, -1, 1, 999, 1, 1, 999, -1, 1]})

print(df)

    group     id  active
0       1  A_410      -1
1       1  B_171      -1
2       1  X_218     999
3       2  A_685      -1
4       2  B_305      -1
5       2  C_407       1
6       2  X_202     999
7       3  B_989       1
8       3  C_616       1
9       3  X_267     999
10      4  A_112      -1
11      5  C_358       1
```

My goal is simple enough to formulate: I want to view only the groups having a least one active id in them (an active id is flagged with a 1).

The resulting DataFrame should look like this:

```
    group     id  active
1       2  A_685      -1
2       2  B_305      -1
3       2  C_407       1
4       2  X_202     999
5       3  B_989       1
6       3  C_616       1
7       3  X_267     999
8       5  C_358       1
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how to formulate this in Python/Pandas syntax. I searched previous post using appropriate keywords but could not find a similar problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare value `1` and test it at least one `True` per group by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html), last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df['active'].eq(1).groupby(df['group']).transform('any')]
print (df)
    group     id  active
3       2  A_685      -1
4       2  B_305      -1
5       2  C_407       1
6       2  X_202     999
7       3  B_989       1
8       3  C_616       1
9       3  X_267     999
11      5  C_358       1
```

Another solution check all groups with `1` and filter original column `group` by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df = df[df['group'].isin(df.loc[df['active'].eq(1), 'group'])]
```